# Merging multiple dataframes by column and row

Tags: r, database, dataframe, merge

I've created a dataframe as follows

`test <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(1:60, each =11)), time = (c(rep(0:10))), resp = NA, liver = NA)`

I would like to merge it with other dataframes, such as this one named `resp_test`, for every corresponding `ID` and `time` in the `test` dataframe.

```
ID  time   resp  
1       0 51
1       1 22
1       2 74
1       3 32
1       4 23
1       5 21
1       6 12
1       7 84
1       8 21
1       9 92
1       10 78
```

However, not all IDs in `resp_test` have the complete (0 -> 10) `time` data on the `resp` variable, like this one. Please note that the data for variable `time` = 4 is missing, as well as from `time`= 7 to `time` = 10.

```
    ID          time resp
1   13072516    2   NA
2   12964437    3   7.2
3   12964437    3   0.8
4   12964437    5   14.4
5   12964437    5   1.6
6   12964437    6   20.7
7   12964437    6   2.3
8   12964437    7   45.0
9   12964437    7   5.0
10  12964437    7   22.5
11  12964437    7   2.5
12  13115001    0   28.8
13  13115001    0   22.3
```

I have tried
`merge(test, resp_test, by = "time")` but all I got was a empty data frame.

Any tips on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(test, resp_test, by = "time")
```

Comment: It worked wonderfully. I haven't thought of using ```left_join```, nor did I know you could use ```by = c("ID", "time")```. 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To merge by both `ID` and `time`, you should do:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% 
  select(-resp) %>% 
  left_join(resp_test, by = c("ID", "time"))
```

Comment: It worked wonderfully. I haven't thought of using ```left_join```, nor did I know you could use ```by = c("ID", "time")```. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: May I ask, what's the difference between using merge() and left_join()?